# Problems with background execution on Android 11 devices

Tags: android, bluetooth, samsung-mobile, android-11

Recently I have discovered that about 2 months ago there was released Android 11 update for Samsung devices.

Samsung has in this version of OS decided to really strictly suspend the apps/services running in the background ([more info](https://dontkillmyapp.com/samsung))

So e.g. when app I am working on goes to background and phone is locked, all BT communication is almost immediately suspended. When I unlock the screen, in that exact moment all threads are not suspended anymore and execution continues.

OS therefore completely ignores the foreground service mechanism.
[Official documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services)

Also when I try to add my app to the list of "Never sleeping apps" (some alternative to battery optimization whitelist on Android 11) - app is still getting suspended + this whitelisting mechanism appears to be unstable and even when I add my app to the whitelist, app disappears from the list after few hours.

**My questions:**

- Have you seen similar issues on Android 11 too ? What helped to resolve the issue?
- Is this only Samsung specific issue or even Pixel devices do the same optimization (ignoring foreground service and whitelist)?

Thanks for any input.

Comment: I also have this problem. I use Firebase and simply don't update, don't send the data.

Comment: So far I have not found any info on this, you just have to add your app to Not optimized list, and even then some optimizations are applied.

Answer (score 0):

sadly this is a huge and common problem and my repsonse will probably not fix it for you, but give you some more insights and possible work-arounds. Have a look at [dontkillmyapp.com](https://dontkillmyapp.com).

Especially [dontkillmyapp.com/samsung](https://dontkillmyapp.com/samsung):

> On Android 11 Samsung will prevent apps work in background by default unless you exclude apps from battery optimizations. This is a severe divergence from standard Android process management policies.
> Yes, this is a long way to go! Devs cannot ask for it automatically as they risk being kicked out from Play Store due to policy violations.

Also I can highly recommend very insightful [the fun talk](https://dontkillmyapp.com/press) fron Droidcon Berlin 2021.